# Is it possible to get status code from response in React Native WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview, single-sign-on

I would like to perform a specific action inside mobile app if WebView returns status code 200. JS fetch does not qualify because the WebView is used to load login page, such as SSO login. I need to be able to see if login has been successful (it returns status code 200), and close WebView and perform additional authentication steps in the mobile app.